# Selenium WebDriver in Java. Select by tag ClassName and parent ClassName

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I need to find an element with tag *select* and ClassName

```
fare-finder__calendar__month-selector__dropdown
```

which is within a *div* with ClassName

```
fare-finder__calendar--outbound
```

The problem is that between them are other divs I don't care about.
Currently I'm using the following solution:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.fare-finder__calendar--outbound div div div div label select.fare-finder__calendar__month-selector__dropdown")).click();
```

But I would like to get rid off the tags between them

```
div div div div label
```

Can you help me with a solution to ignore all the tags which are between the ones I'm interested in?

Thanks,

Comment: you can use answer provided by anonygoose or use xpath axes https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you locate an element, you can locate elements inside that element by doing another findElement call.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.fare-finder__calendar--outbound")).findElement(By.cssSelector("select.fare-finder__calendar__month-selector__dropdown"));
```

You could also use a (sensible) xpath:

```
By.xpath("//div[@class='parentElementClass']//select[@class='childElementClass']");
```

I'm a lot less familiar with CSS selector, but it should allow any child location:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.fare-finder__calendar--outbound select.fare-finder__calendar__month-selector__dropdown")).click();
```

You should not need to specify all elements in between, that is signified with the > character.

**Update**:

I've edited the above code to compile properly, and to fully represent your pages actual classes.  Tested and working against this mock page https://5d70fb99-bb95-4031-bdec-e46bd79a44fd.htmlpasta.com/

If neither of these locators work, there may something odd about the actual page you're automating.  It may also be useful to post minimal HTML code that recreates the problem, as well as the version of Selenium-Webdriver you're using, and what Driver (Chrome, Firefox, IE, Edge?) you're using.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
The first option doesn't work, it does not compile.
The second one maybe is a good one, but for I need to use only cssSelector in that method, for some specific reason.
I tried firstly the 3rd one, but it doesn't work for me, the selector is not found.

Comment: Sorry about that, was posting from phone and missed a couple of parentheses.  Updated to fix that now :)